# Could not find main class : Program will exit

Tags: eclipse, java, program-entry-point, .class-file

I was messing with the JRE setup on Eclipse. Originally the project was set to 1.6 and when set to 1.7, my program started showing a lot of errors. So when i switched back to 1.6, all the compile time errors vanished but i have a new problem now.
This was shown on the console when i tried to run the started class containing the main function. The .class files all exist. Please advice.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Demo : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: I think you're trying to run the program with an older version of the JRE than the compile target. E.g. you've compiled to 1.6 bytecode and run with a 1.4 JRE - just check all the settings again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version 51.0 means the are still class files compiled with Java 7. This files wont run with a JRE 6. You have to recompile them first (Rebuild project or clean compile using ant/maven).

Comment: it seems i had messed up the JRE configuration while trying to use strings in switch-cases. thanks a lot from the prompt reply.

Answer (score 1):

Check if java versions match in your Java Build path and Java Compiler in Project properties. I think you compiled with 1.6 and is trying to run with java 1.7